# How to order grouped boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this type of data:

```
well <- structure(list(Pos_in_turn = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "10", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "8", "9", "9"), d = c(0.258, 0.191, 0.213, 0.078, 0.169, 
0.105, 0.053, 0.354, 0.208, 0.269, 0.198, 0.309, 0.207, 0.171, 
0.094, 0.183, 0.094, 0.079, 0.199, 0.105, 0.202, 0.123, 0.237, 
0.249, 0.298, 0.125, 0.149, 0.138, 0.143, 0.096, 0.118, 0.284, 
0.134, 0.117, 0.116, 0.108, 0.145, 0.547, 0.173, 0.152, 0.101, 
0.156, 0.237, 0.082, 0.138, 0.172, 0.116, 0.068, 0.354, 0.198, 
0.081, 0.098, 0.259, 0.111, 0.119, 0.155, 0.068, 0.143, 0.182, 
0.102, 0.181, 0.182, 0.318, 0.118, 0.255, 0.089, 0.158, 0.319, 
0.061, 0.134, 0.121, 0.285, 0.147, 0.192, 0.152, 0.191, 0.093, 
0.176, 0.237, 0.218, 0.149, 0.249, 0.166, 0.243, 0.191, 0.194, 
0.234, 0.372), w = c("well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", "well", 
"well", "well", "well")), row.names = c(NA, -88L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to boxplot `d` by `Pos_in_turn` but find that both in `base R` and `ggplot2` the levels of `Pos_in_turn`, which range from 1-10, are not displayed in continuous order:

```
boxplot(well$d ~ well$Pos_in_turn, 
        main = "How long does it take to say 'well'?\n(in 10-word turns from BNC-C)", cex.main = 0.9,
        xlab = "Position in turn",
        ylab = "Duration (sec.)")
# or:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(well, 
       aes(x = Pos_in_turn, y = d)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "How long does it take to say 'well'?\n(in 10-word turns from BNC-C)")
```

How can that continuous order on the x-axis be achieved?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just use `well$Pos_in_turn <- as.numeric(well$Pos_in_turn)` before you plot, or better yet, identify the cause *why* the values are stored as character in the first place and fix it there...

Answer (score 1):

They're currently a string so just convert them to a number with `as.numeric`